# Server-side Yajra datatable columns:[] manipulation

Tags: javascript, laravel, datatables, yajra-datatable

I want to manipulate yajra datatables

```
columns:[
    { data: 'fname', name: 'members.fname' },
    { data: 'fname', name: 'employees.emp_fname' }
]
```

using the render function shown below and it didn't workout. There is an error in the return statement. The table doesn't render any data. I just couldn't find the right workaround. I already used `alias` and `addColumn` and works good but the problem is it won't allow searching in names. That is why I came up with this kind of code line because it will maybe allow searching if it works. Please help on this. Thanks.

```
p3bills_table = $('#table-p3bills').DataTable({
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    order: [
        [
            1, "asc"
        ]
    ],
    ajax: {
        url: "{{ route('get.p3bills') }}",
    },
    columns: [
        { data:'id', name:'p3bills.id' },
        { data:'id', name:'p3bills.id', orderable: true },
        { data:'p3loan_id', name:'p3loan_id' },
        { data:'schedule', name:'p3bills.schedule' },
        {
            render: function (data, type, full, meta) {
                if (full.member_id == 0) {
                    return data:'fname', name: 'employees.emp_fname';
                } else {
                    return data:'fname', name: 'members.fname';
                }
            }
        },
        { data:'lname', name:'members.lname' },
        { data:'mname', name:'members.mname' }
    ]
});
```

**Controller**

```
 public function getP3bills(){

    $p3bills = P3bill::leftJoin('p3payments', 'p3payments.p3bill_id', '=', 'p3bills.id')
                     ->leftJoin('members', 'members.id', '=', 'p3bills.member_id')
                     ->leftJoin('employees', 'employees.id', '=', 'p3bills.employee_id')
                     ->select(['members.id','members.lname','members.fname','members.mname','members.extension','employees.id','employees.emp_lname','employees.emp_fname','employees.emp_mname','employees.emp_extension','p3bills.*','p3payments.payment_amount','p3payments.or_number'])
                     ->selectRaw(  '('.
            'CASE'.
            ' WHEN members.id=0 THEN employees.emp_fname'.
            ' ELSE members.fname'.
            ' END'.
        ') AS person_name' );
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to handle this situation on the backend instead.

I assume you're using Yajra DataTables [service implementation](https://datatables.yajrabox.com/service).

You can use [`CASE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/case.html) statement to determine what will be returned based on your condition.

For example:

```
/**
 * Get query source of dataTable.
 *
 * @param \App\Models\User $model
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
 */
public function query(User $model)
{
    $query = $model->newQuery()
        ->select()
        ->selectRaw(
            '('.
                'CASE'.
                ' WHEN members.id=0 THEN employees.emp_fname'.
                ' ELSE members.fname'.
                ' END'.
            ') AS person_name'
        );

    return $query;
}
```

To enable searching on this new column you would need to call [`filterColumn()`](https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/8.0/filter-column) method.

Depending on your Laravel DataTables version and chosen implementation method your code may be different. For example, code below is for Laravel DataTables v9 using service implementation.

```
/**
 * Build DataTable class.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $query Results from query() method.
 * @return \Yajra\DataTables\DataTableAbstract
 */
public function dataTable($query)
{
    return datatables($query)
        ->filterColumn('person_name', function($query, $keyword) {
            $query->whereRaw(
                '('.
                    'CASE'.
                    ' WHEN members.id=0 THEN employees.emp_fname'.
                    ' ELSE members.fname'.
                    ' END'.
                ') ILIKE ?', 
                [ '%' . sql_escape_like($keyword) . '%' ]
            );
        });
}
```

Also I am using the following helper method to escape special characters in the `LIKE` / `ILIKE` clause.

```
if (! function_exists('sql_escape_like')) {
    /**
     * Escape special characters for SQL query with LIKE condition.
     *
     * @param  string $value
     * @return string
     */
    function sql_escape_like($value)
    {
        return str_replace(['\\', '%', '_'], ['\\\\', '\\%', '\\_'], $value);
    }
}
```

Then use `{ data:'person_name' }` as your column definition in your JavaScript DataTables initialization code.

Comment: I haven't tried this one yet. I'll try this later when I get home. This looks good. But I have tried using alias a couple of days ago, the problem is the names can't be searched in the datatable because the name used in alias doesn't exist in the database, in this case, the person_name. I hope this code goes well. I'll give you updates later.

Comment: Is this working when the names are searched in the datatables?

Comment: I edited my post and showed my controller function, I applied your code, and it doesn't display in the table the employees.emp_fname only the members.fname. And the searching doesn't work.

Comment: @Eli, did you replace your column definition with `{ data: 'person_name' }`?

Comment: Yes sir. { data: 'person_name', name: 'person_name' }, search not working, and I don't know why it won't show the employees.emp_fname

Comment: @Eli, I added more details to enable searching. Also I suspect that the reason `employees.emp_fname` is not showing is because `members.id=0` condition is incorrect. Check your condition, maybe it should be `members.id IS NULL`?

Comment: this is working man. thank you so much. and it is actually p3bills.member_id=0, this is the right condition.

Comment: how about if I include the lname and mname? Do I have to copy the selectRaw portion and create another filterColumn? or I can just manipulate it in the CASE part?

Comment: there is a regex search error sir. also there is a pop up like this: DataTables warning: table id=table-p3bills-all - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by [Gyrocode.com](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61172372/5808894), check the status in the Controller and render
the element using a pseudo column. In the Controller you could do so,

```
$bills = Bill::all(); // Your Model Query goes here

return datatables($bills)
        ->addColumn('fname', function ($bill) {
            if ($bill->member_id == 0) {
                return $bill->employee->fname; // Employee First Name
            }

            return $bill->member->fname; // Member First Name
        })
        ->toJson();
```

and in the JavaScript you could use it as,

```
{ data: 'fname' }
```

Comment: Does this code allow searching of first names? Coz I read in yajra that defined names in addColumn function cannot be searched.

Comment: add Column is a pseudo column and doesn't allow search across them. More info here https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables/issues/139

Comment: @linktoahref, you have a good alternative solution but with no search working. If you use `filterColumn('fname', function ($query, $keyword){ }`, you would be able to customize search criteria.